# Javascript window.print() defaults to PDF

Tags: javascript

A print button on a site I am working on opens a new window and populates it with some HTML. I call `window.print()` which works fine, but the default printer for myself and others who have tested it is always a PDF writer if one is available on the system. Is there a way to open the print dialog box with the appropriate default printer selected so that the user does not have to select their printer every time?

Comment: JavaScript has no control over a default printer setting in the user's operating system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is all dependent on your browser.
 Nothing to do with the code at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can only change the layout like this:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@page { size: landscape;}
</style>
```

but not any other stuff i guess.
Hope this helps.